# .fadeOut() not working

Tags: jquery, fadeout

I'm having a problem with my `.fadeOut()` not working when a user clicks "No", and I know it's because `div.confirm` is embedded within the `span`, which is where the `.fadeIn()` function is called.

I'm working on a project that requires this HTML hierarchy, but I need the "No" button to `.fadeOut()` the confirmation box.

[Non-working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/motioncrafter/wv3hy612/)

My HTML:

```
<span>Delete File
<div class="confirm">Are you sure?
  <div class="yes">
   Yes
  </div>
  <div class="no">
   No
  </div>
</div>
</span>
```

JS:

```
$('span').click(function () {
    $('.confirm').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.no').click(function () {
    $('.confirm').fadeOut(100);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to use [**e.stopPropagation();**](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

```
$('span').click(function () {
    $('.confirm').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.no').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.confirm').fadeOut(100);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wv3hy612/1/)

**And ,** to be more clear if you have more than one span  you can use

```
$('span').click(function () {
    $(this).find('.confirm').fadeIn(100);
});

$('.no').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.confirm').fadeOut(100);
})
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/wv3hy612/4/)

Comment: This worked great. Thank you. I tried using just `stopPropagation()` but it didn't work. What is the purpose of "e", or "event"?

Comment: @user1661677 e mean event .. I provide my question with the documentation https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is moving the .confirm div outside the span - it should prevent the firing of the span's event and still work just fine.

[Yey-working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv3hy612/3/)

```
<span>Delete File</span>
 <div class="confirm">Are you sure?
  <div class="yes">
  Yes
  </div>
  <div class="no">
  No
  </div>
 </div>
```